# Flask: 404 Not Found

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a REST api using Flask. The problem that I have is, every time i try to visit the route, it returns 404 Not found both in the browser and in the console.

This is my code:

```py
try:
    import urllib.request
    from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
except ImportError:
    import urllib2
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    from cookielib import CookieJar
import re
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)
cj = CookieJar()
try:
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
except:
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17')]

@app.route('/imagelookup/<string:img>/', methods=['GET'])
def imageLookUp(img):
    #imagepath = 'http://i.imgur.com/RZPXtOU.jpg'
    #imagepath = 'http://i.imgur.com/eDz2BE5.jpg'
    #imagepath = 'https://image.dhgate.com/0x0s/f2-albu-g6-M01-09-33-rBVaR1qZVlWAdONFAALxr6pjOMU350.jpg/2018-new-arrival-hot-sexy-summer-beach-bikini.jpg'
    imagepath = img

    googlepath = 'http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url='+imagepath

    sourceCode = opener.open(googlepath).read().decode('utf-8')

    regex = r'<input class="gLFyf gsfi"(.*?)>'

    pattern = re.compile(regex)

    findElement = re.findall(pattern, sourceCode)

    for eachElement in findElement:
        validEl = eachElement

    newregex = r'value="(.*?)"'

    newpattern = re.compile(newregex)

    extractName = re.findall(newpattern, validEl)

    return jsonify({'imgObj': extractName})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I expect a JSON response but instead, it returns a 404 response code.

This is the URL i tried visiting on my browser: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/imagelookup/https://image.dhgate.com/0x0s/f2-albu-g6-M01-09-33-rBVaR1qZVlWAdONFAALxr6pjOMU350.jpg/2018-new-arrival-hot-sexy-summer-beach-bikini.jpg`

This is a screenshot of the console, if needed: [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8re2.jpg)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `img` to be the full url passed after the route prefix, use a type of `path` rather than `string` -- see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules

"Path - like string but also accepts slashes"

So your route should be

```
@app.route('/imagelookup/<path:img>/', methods=['GET'])
def imageLookUp(img):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It should probably return a descriptive error, than 404 :)

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu Flask can’t do that because it can’t know that you intended that route to match. All it can tell you is that nothing matched, and the standard response for that scenario is the 404 error code.

Comment: Hi, when i use a path that has '?' in it, it automatically appends '/' before the '?' so something like this: ```https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/isocial-57d19.appspot.com/o/post_ec56cb24-3407-40c5-9c28-8018d24a12bf.jpg?alt=media&token=8e6dae2a-50cc-4aa2-8967-f0b71a8f50b0``` turns to something like this: ```https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/isocial-57d19.appspot.com/o/post_ec56cb24-3407-40c5-9c28-8018d24a12bf.jpg/?alt=media&token=8e6dae2a-50cc-4aa2-8967-f0b71a8f50b0``` please do you know how to fix it?